# Can Bootstrap panel be reordered in different sequence when seen in mobile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the panel in the same way when displays in desktop view but want to change the sequence when seen in mobile.In mobile view, the first panel `First Name` and the last panel `Last Name` should be seen one after another. I googled it but could not found the solution. Please help me.

```
<div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>                 
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Address</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Company</div>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>              
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is done with Bootstrap's `order` classes.

---

### **Bootstrap 4.0+**

You can use `order-1` through `order-12` and the col's will be ordered from 1-12. To set responsive break points in this you can use them like `order-sm-6` and `order-sm-7`.

In your code, to move the lastName to the second slot you would reorder them and set the order custom for the breakpoint and higher like so:

```
    <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6 order-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>                 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6 order-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>              
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6 order-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Address</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6 order-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Company</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Putting them in the current order you have on `md` and up.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes Has more information.

---

**Bootstrap 3**

Ordering is done with push/pull.

So `col-md-push-3` would push the column over 3/12 if it could snap. An example below being the columns are rendered in code order below md, but are reversed md and above:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

In this case (pushing last name back to the end for md and up):

```
<div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>                 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-push-8">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>              
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Address</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container active col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Company</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But order will change in desktop view as well. I want to reorder only when it is seen in mobile

Comment: Bootstrap (and mobile development in general now) has a motto of 'mobile first'. So you code the mobile one default, and reorder/resize for desktop. So this code I've provided accomplishes your goals of order on all sizes

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. But it is not working in the way which i need. If I put your code then, in desktop view, it is displaying `First Name` then `Last Name` and then the rest. But I want this only when it is seen in mobile.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Sorry to ask you but how to check the version

Comment: What is the CDN link you're using in the head?

Comment: It is showing something like this `*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.0 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */`

Comment: So you're on an older version, I've updated my post to reflect how the ordering classes work for Bootstrap 3

Comment: I will be grateful to you if you could provide me the same in Boostrap 3 as well. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If I put `col-md-push-8` then the `Last Name` gets disappeared and only seen in mobile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167218/discussion-between-raj-and-j-livengood).

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue.your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @J Livengood, if you feel that this question is useful to future developers on this site, then can you please upvote. Thank you!